# nginx https 443 redirection from no subdomain to 'www' subdomain

Tags: nginx, https, 301-redirect

My configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.mydomain.com$1;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  return 301 https://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;

  if ($host !~* ^(www.mydomain.com)$ ) {
    return 444;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /path/to/www.mydomain.com_chain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/www.mydomain.com.key;

  ...
}
```

What *does work*:

- redirection from `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com`
- redirection from `www.mydomain.com` to `https://www.mydomain.com`

What *does NOT work* correctly:

- when I enter `https://mydomain.com` directly into the browser the redirect to `www.mydomain.com` simply does not occur, but the request is passed onto the application server as `https://mydomain.com`

  - it appears as if the port 80 "entrance" is being skipped and the server is being accessed directly at port 443, but I'm not an Nginx expert so I'm unable to tell

What is the solution for the `https://mydomain.com` problem above?

Answer (score 2):

Use an if statement in your SSL server block to check the host:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /path/to/www.mydomain.com_chain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/www.mydomain.com.key;



  if ($host = 'mydomain.com' ) {
     rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://www.mydomain.com/$1  permanent;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm reluctant to use `if` in this context; read [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil).

Comment: "Directive if has problems when used in location context".  This is not a location context

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected the reason was because port 80 was being skipped and port 443 accessed directly. Adding the following `server` block enabled the redirect:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /path/to/www.mydomain.com_chain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/www.mydomain.com.key;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.mydomain.com$1;
}
```

If anyone knows of a better or more elegant solution please add your answer.

Comment: You probably want to add `permanent` at the end of your rewrite line to do a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to avoid if because [if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil), also I prefer using return over rewrite because it doesn't need to run a regex engine.

```
server {
  #default server that catches all undefined host names
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 444;
}
server {
  #redirecting server for non-www ssl and non ssl domains
  listen 80;
  liste 443 ssl;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  ssl_certificate     /path/to/www.mydomain.com_chain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/www.mydomain.com.key;
  return 301 https://www.mydomain.com$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
}
server {
  # redirecting server for www non ssl server
  listen 80; 
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  return 301 https://mydomain.com$request_uri$is_args$query_string;
}
server {
  # main server config
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate     /path/to/www.mydomain.com_chain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/www.mydomain.com.key;
  # remaining config...
}
```